# Not sure why I keep getting expecting end of input syntax error

Tags: ruby

```
puts 'Lets talk to grandma'
talk = gets.chomp 
x = 100

while x > 0  
  if talk == talk.upcase    
    puts 'NO NOT SINCE' + ' ' + rand(1900).to_s + '!'   
  else      
    puts 'HUH'  
  end
 ​
  if​ talk == ​'BYE' 
    ​break​
  end   
end
```

Comment: Put your BYE-if expression above the other if-expression, then put your user prompt and assignment into the while-loop.

Comment: like this?


x = 100

while x > 0

puts 'Lets talk to grandma'

talk = gets.chomp

  if​ talk == ​'BYE' 
    ​ break​
 end


 if talk == talk.upcase
 
 puts 'NO NOT SINCE' + ' ' + rand(1900).to_s + '!'

 else 
 
 puts 'HUH'

 end
 ​

end

Comment: Yeah that should work

Answer (score 1):

There are some unicode characters in the code you've provided.

As the code doesn't have problems to run, despite of an infinite loop, I've used `git diff` to check it.

I've edited the line with the `if` statement, and there you can see:

```
-  if<U+200B> talk == <U+200B>'BYE'
-    break<U+200B>
+  if talk == 'BYE'
+    break
```

`<U+200B>` maybe there's an encoding issue with your text editor or IDE.